# Reading Float values in android app being sent from RFduino

Tags: android, floating-point, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, rfduino

i am using the lann rfduino test app and its service as basis for my android app. here is a link to his github account [https://github.com/lann/RFDuinoTest]
I have the following Code in RFDUINO so that everytime i send a value to the rfduino from my android app it sends me back the float value 2.34

```
#include <RFduinoBLE.h>
void setup() {
RFduinoBLE.advertisementData = "ledbtn";
RFduinoBLE.begin();
}
void loop() {
} 
void RFduinoBLE_onReceive(char *data, int len)
{
RFduinoBLE.send(2.34);
}
```

when i try to do 
byte[] ff = intent.getByteArrayExtra(RFduinoService.EXTRA_DATA);
Float.parseFloat(HexAsciiHelper.bytesToAsciiMaybe(ff)) 
i get the following errors

```html
02-26 07:07:48.231: E/AndroidRuntime(5362): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-26 07:07:48.231: E/AndroidRuntime(5362): Process: com.example.letsdothisanotherway, PID: 5362
02-26 07:07:48.231: E/AndroidRuntime(5362): java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=com.rfduino.ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE flg=0x10 (has extras) } in com.example.letsdothisanotherway.Newideaat2inthemorning$4@429ce1e8
02-26 07:07:48.231: E/AndroidRuntime(5362):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:782)
02-26 07:07:48.231: E/AndroidRuntime(5362):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
02-26 07:07:48.231: E/AndroidRuntime(5362):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
02-26 07:07:48.231: E/AndroidRuntime(5362):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
02-26 07:07:48.231: E/AndroidRuntime(5362):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
02-26 07:07:48.231: E/AndroidRuntime(5362):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-26 07:07:48.231: E/AndroidRuntime(5362):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-26 07:07:48.231: E/AndroidRuntime(5362):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
02-26 07:07:48.231: E/AndroidRuntime(5362):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
02-26 07:07:48.231: E/AndroidRuntime(5362):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-26 07:07:48.231: E/AndroidRuntime(5362): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-26 07:07:48.231: E/AndroidRuntime(5362):  at java.lang.StringToReal.parseFloat(StringToReal.java:285)
02-26 07:07:48.231: E/AndroidRuntime(5362):  at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:300)
02-26 07:07:48.231: E/AndroidRuntime(5362):  at com.example.letsdothisanotherway.Newideaat2inthemorning$4.onReceive(Newideaat2inthemorning.java:115)
02-26 07:07:48.231: E/AndroidRuntime(5362):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:772)
02-26 07:07:48.231: E/AndroidRuntime(5362):  ... 9 more
```

can you help me please?????

Comment: your RFduinoService is null on `byte[] ff = intent.getByteArrayExtra(RFduinoService.EXTRA_DATA);`